# Problem with adding a user in Watson Studio

Tags: cognos, watson-studio

Problem with adding a user in Watson Studio, I am in IBM trying to add a standard IBM user within Cognos Analytics that I use in Watson Studio and when I try, says that user does not use an IBM email and therefore can not be added, but this is wrong, it's an IBM email, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If IBM email and IBMID are synonymous in your post, you could have the individual attempt to logon to http://myibm.ibm.com/dashboard/ to see if their IBMID matches the contact email address setup for the account.